# Combining 2 sql queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I spent many hours combining my query into one. I have 3 database table. This is example schema.
[image]

I have only user name from session. I need take all tickets from database from user company.

Example:

User A working in company B.

Company B have many workers. Workers creating tickets. 

User A after login see all tickets from yours company.

I now done this using 2 query:

- Take usera A company id

- Take tickets where users work in specifist company.

Comment: (1) Please provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Also, edit your question and include the queries you are trying to combine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM User u1 
INNER JOIN User u2 on u2.id_company = u1.id_company
INNER JOIN Ticket t on t.id_author = u2.id_user
WHERE u1.Name = @SessionUser
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select t.*
from users u join
     tickets t
     on u.id_user = t.id_author
where u.company_id = (select u2.company_id from users u2 where u2.id_user = 'UserA');
```

Comment: What is faster your result or @JoelCoehoorn ?

Comment: @seti . . . You should test it and try it out.  With an index on `users(id_user)`, I would expect the performance to be similar.  However, this version returns the ticket information (which is what you seem to want) and doesn't have duplicate column names, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Joins are typically faster than subqueries, however a lot of DBMS' optimize subqueries into joins, so the difference between the queries is probably not important. Below is a reworked version of Gordon Linoff's query removing the subquery.

```
   select t.* from Users u1 
   join User u2 on u2.id_company = u1.id_company
   join Ticket t on t.id_author = u1.id_user
   where u1.id.user = 'User1';
```

However again, if your database optimizes the SQL the difference is negligible.

Comment: I changed join to where clause. HQL not support join.